# Convert SQL date datatype to string

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am writing something in VB and need to convert a SQL date (not datetime) into a string. This should be an easy convertion, however toString does not work and I cannot find anything online .
The part of the code I'm working on looks like this:

```
    Dim incomingDate As String
    incomingDate = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString()
```

When the data being put in the gridview is a DateTime datatype this works fine. If it's simply Date, it gives me the following error message:

"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index"

I've also tried this work-around but it didn't work

```
    Dim incomingDate As String
    Dim d As New DateTime
    d = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells(5).Text)

    incomingDate = Date.Parse(row.Cells(5).Text)
```

Same error...

Comment: What exactly is the column type for the "date" of which you speak? Which DBMS? How are you querying for data?

Comment: The column type is 'date'. In all other tables it's datetime, however for this one they just used 'date'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you trying to read the value back out of a form control like a Table or Grid? The error you receive makes me thing that `row.Cells(5)` doesn't exist. Do you have six columns? Remember to index the cells starting with 0, not 1. Other than that, retrieving the text via the `.Text` property should be ok. No need to parse into a Date unless you want to change the format.

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the problem... thanks Cory! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can use `convert(varchar, mySqlDate, 101)` to emit a string instead of a date.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I am running the code in Visual Studio, loading the query into a SqlDataAdapter object. Is this something I can add into the SQL SELECT statement?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of `select mySqlDate ...` (which returns a SqlDate), plug this in `select convert(varchar, mySqlDate, 101) ...` and get back a string instead.